# Redux toolkit queries from a button action

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I'm using Redux Toolkit (React native) and the `useGetGenreMoviesQuery` hook to fetch movies when the page loads.

```
const { data, isLoading, error } = useGetGenreMoviesQuery(page);
```

Now, I want to trigger the same API call when a button is pressed. However, when I tried to destructure the `useGetGenreMoviesQuery` hook for the button press:

```
const [getMovies, { data, isLoading, error }] = useGetGenreMoviesQuery(page);
```

I got the error:

> 'TypeError: Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance. In order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a Symbol.iterator method.'

How can I properly make the API call with a button press in this scenario?

I tried removing the const array and tried to call the same API using refetch from the redux toolkit.

```
const { data, isLoading, error, refetch } = useGetGenreMoviesQuery(page);
```

But it is not working.

I have to make the API call again on a user interaction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the `refetch` function *should* work in this case, but the more conventional way to effect a query call as a result of some UI event or in a callback is to use a [Lazy Query](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/created-api/hooks#uselazyquery). The lazy query hooks ***do*** return an array containing the trigger function and results.

Export the generated `useLazyGetGenreMoviesQuery` hook from your API slice and call the trigger function in the button's `onClick` callback handler.

```
...

const [
  getMovies,
  { data, isLoading, error }
] = useLazyGetGenreMoviesQuery();

...

const clickHandler = async (page) => {
  try {
    const result = await getMovies(page).unwrap();
    // success, any additional logic
  } catch(error) {
    // failure
  }
}

...

<button type="button" onClick={clickHandler}>
  Get Movies
</button>

...
```